# Connecting a wired interface breaks internet access via wireless in Windows 10

Tags: networking, windows-10, routing

**[EDIT]**

After a clean install on my desktop the issue was resolved. I now have all the applications I previously had and all traffic is still routed correctly, so I don't think any app was interfering with the connection.

All in all, the issue was resolved by reinstalling the OS, but I couldn't pinpoint what caused the problem in the first place.

**[\EDIT]**

On my desktop running Windows 10, I have two network interfaces; a wireless USB adapter and wired onboard ethernet.

Through the wireless I connect to my ISP's router with a DHCP that serves the `192.168.1.1/24` subnet. The wired interface connects to a router that routes inside a private network utilising the `10.0.0.0` subnet and has a DHCP that serves the `10.x.x.1/24 subnet` (due to uniquely identifiable addressing in the private network the actual IPs are deducted).

When only connected to the wireless interface, I have access to the internet. A few seconds after I connect to the wired interface (still being connected to the wire) I lose connection to the Internet.

I have two persistent routes on the routing table. First one being:

```
0.0.0.0 mask 0.0.0.0 192.168.1.1 1
```

and the second one being:

```
10.0.0.0 mask 255.0.0.0 10.x.x.x 1
```

[image: (screen cap of persistent routes)]

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that each route has it's weight set correctly. Even though you have routes set manually, both DHCP probably is assigning a default route. If the weights are not set, then the OS uses the last successfully connected NIC as the highest priority for default routes, which is the 10.x network.

Comment: Manually setting the weight was the second thing I did, just after setting the persistent route for the 10.0.0.0 network. In the case of the question it didn't fix the problem but after a clean install it worked.